# Get A List of People who are not "Users" but registered for my system

Tags: c#, asp.net

Not much experience with C# and ASP.net.

Trying to generate a list of people who are awaiting to be assigned the "User" status but what I have just shows everyone in the system, Authoirzed Users and unauthorized.

My controller method is:

```
 //GET
    public ActionResult UsersNoRoles()
    {
        var users = (from u in db.UserProfiles
                     select u);


        IList<UserProfile> usersNoRoles = new List<UserProfile>();


        foreach (var item in users)
        {

            SelectList list = new SelectList(Roles.GetUsersInRole(item.UserName));

            if (list.Count() == 0)
            {
                usersNoRoles.Add(item);

            }
        }


        return View(usersNoRoles);
    }
```

Then I'm sending it onto my view in a table:

```
@if ((Model != null) && (TempData["Error"] == null))
{
<tr>
   <th>
        Username
    </th>
    </tr>
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName) 
            </td>
        </tr>
}
```

I've been instructed to not use View Models also.

I want a list of people not authorized for the system.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I get Users not authorized in a list

Comment: Which property of user indicate whether that user is registered or not.

Comment: Currently you are getting the following: "Gets a list of users in the specified role." see documentation: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.getusersinrole%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: you are passing the new list of userprofile with user role, apply a linq query on database and filter your result like: `var userprofile = db.UserProfiles.where(t=> t.UserRole != 'user').ToList();`

Comment: from your code it looks like you your trying to find users who have no roles?

Comment: @Mr.Bhanushali I'm using the out of the box code from C#. Only table I can access is UserProfiles which don't have Roles in it. They are in WebPages_Roles etc

Comment: @jamiedanq yes thats the plan. I want to show the Admin who needs to be authorised

Answer (score 0):

Your code is frankly ... broken

```
   foreach (var item in users)
    {
        // this is broken and doesnt add any functionality should simply go away,
        // item.UserName shouldn't have anything to do with role of the user,
        // you are creating this list for every single iteration trough the userlist
        SelectList list = new SelectList(Roles.GetUsersInRole(item.UserName));

        // here you are adding the user to your list only if its empty, by your result it seems like it's always empty
        // that means that the previous statement in your code doesn't really
        // filter anything
        if (list.Count() == 0)
        {
            usersNoRoles.Add(item);

        }
    }
```

Let's do it like this:

```
var usersNoRoles = new List<UserProfile>();

foreach(var user in users)
{
    if(user.UserRole != "User")
    usersNoRoles.Add(user);
}
```

Comment: I'm using the out of the box code so I can't use the user.UserRole.

Comment: So you are saying that you want to filter users based on their role yet you can not look at what role they have? That's a tough one ...

Comment: Yep, tell me about it. Been wrecking the head for the past days.

Comment: @EoinCasey but can you use the `userManager`?